# Syntax error in create table statement when using foreign key

Tags: delphi, ms-access

I'm using delphi to create a database in MS Access, but when I click the button to add the tables to the database it flags the syntax as being incorrect.

```
cs:='CREATE TABLE tblRecordOfGames ('+
   'Username Varchar CONSTRAINT FK_Username '+
   'REFERENCES tblUsers (Username),'+
   'TimeOfGame Date/Time,'+
   'MovesTaken Integer(3)'+
   'OptimalMoves Integer(3)'+
   'PercentageofOptimalMoves Double(5)'+
   'CreditsWon Integer'+
   'CreditsLost Integer)';

ADOCommand1.CommandText:=cs;
ADOCommand1.Execute;
```

I think it's an issue with the way I'm trying to add the key but I've been having a hard time finding a working example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Several of your data types are wrong, and you are missing several commas.
Setting a field size / precision is only valid for types TEXT and DECIMAL.

See http://allenbrowne.com/ser-49.html (the DDL column).

Your CONSTRAINT is valid, though. :)

Try this:

```
CREATE TABLE tblRecordOfGames (
   Username Text(50) CONSTRAINT FK_Username REFERENCES tblUsers (Username),
   TimeOfGame DateTime,
   MovesTaken Integer,
   OptimalMoves Integer,
   PercentageofOptimalMoves Double,
   CreditsWon Integer,
   CreditsLost Integer)
```

Note: you should add a Primary Key.

Comment: Thanks mate works perfectly, I have the statement for the primary key as a separate command. Took it out while I was trouble shooting that.